# How to convert an AbstractOnSubscribe to an Operator with backpressure support in RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java

I extended `AbstractOnSubscribe` to create my own `OnSubscribe` to be used with `Observable.create(OnSubscribe<T>)` that i named  [`OnSubscribeInputStreamToLines`](https://github.com/Crystark/RxJavaString/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/OnSubscribeInputStreamToLines.java) that basically reads an `InputStream` and calls `onNext` for each line.

The thing is, I also need to do that with the `InputStream` being part of an other `Observable`.

The easy solution would be to do the following:

```java
Observable<InputStream> isObservable = ...;

isObservable
    .flatMap(is -> Observable.create(new OnSubscribeInputStreamToLines(is)));
```

The thing is that would not be really efficient as it would create an Observable for each inputStream. I was thinking I may be able to do this using `Observable.lift`.

**Is there a way so I can easily convert my `OnSubscribeInputStreamToLines` to an `Operator` ?**

I'm mostly worried about backpressure issues as i would call `onNext` for each line of an `InputStream` and although `AbstractOnSubscribe` supports backpressure, I couldn't find an `AbstractOperator` that does the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The distinction here is that your `OnSubscribeInputStreamToLines` is an entry point into the Observable world whereas `lift` is an in-between operator for an existing sequence. Besides, the whole throughput might be dominated by the IO operation behind `InputStream` or the string processing in the operation so I wouldn't worry about that thin wrapper.

`AbstractOnSubscribe` captures the generator-aspect of operators which helps you build backpressure-aware value emitters (cold sources generally) where you can draft out how, when and what values are emitted.

`AbstractOperator`, on the other hand, can't be generalized this way because `Operator`s have more freedom for interacting with upstream values and downstream requests. They are highly customized to a specific task and there is little-to-none common points to them. They can be built from a set of primitives but that's it (I've written hundreds of them).

So don't be afraid of `flatMap`ping over things.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be bothered about creating another Observable for each `InputStream`. The overhead is probably not as large as you might think especially compared to overhead associated with `lift`.

I don't know the nature of the `InputStream`s you are consuming but you should probably consider `Observable.using()` to close those resources safely (on termination or unsubscription).

You are absolutely right to have hesitations about writing a backpressure supporting `Operator`. It is very tricky ground to be stepping on unless you are composing existing `Operator`s.

Comment: I see akarnokd has answered as well. You won't find a more knowledgeable source than him!